# Why doesn't Executor.asCoroutineDispatcher work like newFixedThreadPoolContext?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I thought these two lines would be equivalent execution wise:

```
val context1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2).asCoroutineDispatcher()
val context2 = newFixedThreadPoolContext(2, "Fixed")
```

But when I use "context2" in the code below it works as expected, but "context1" acts like a single thread.

```
val context1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2).asCoroutineDispatcher()

repeat(4) {
    launch {
        withContext(context1) {
            Thread.sleep(2000)
        }
    }
}

context1.close()
```

**Expected**: 2 threads will execute in parallel.  The code should complete in 4 seconds, because to 2 threads sleep for 2 seconds and then repeat.

**Actual**: Only one thread executes and the "repeat" is executed serially, which takes 8 seconds to complete.

Is this a bug?

Or what is meant by this documentation found [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-fixed-thread-pool-context.html)?

> If you need a completely separate thread-pool with scheduling policy
>   that is based on the standard JDK executors, use the following
>   expression: Executors.newFixedThreadPool().asCoroutineDispatcher().

Comment: Could you please post the full example. In your case the `launch` is the important part. `withContext` only switches the thread/context but says nothing about parallelism. The function `launch` starts a new coroutine in a `CoroutineScope` and this scope defines if the coroutines run in parallel. So I need the context around your method to give you an answer.

Comment: You should fix your code to `launch(context2) { Thread.sleep(2000) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with the full code example:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")


fun main() = runBlocking {
    val context1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2).asCoroutineDispatcher()
    val context2 = newFixedThreadPoolContext(2, "Fixed")

    repeat(4) {
        launch {
            withContext(context1) {
                log("Start sleep $it")
                Thread.sleep(2000)
                log("Finished sleep $it")
            }
        }
    }

//    context1.close()
}
```

I discovered the problem is with the "context1.close()".  If I comment out the "context1.close()" it works correctly.  My guess is that the "launch" calls aren't blocking, so the "context1.close()" gets executed before the "withContext" executes on the other threads.  I would have assumed that would cause an error, but it appears to just make it a single thread.